# Bayesian analysis- Normal distribution with unknown mean and variance

Tags: r, bayesian

Suppose we have some data points that we believe they follow $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and both parameters are unknown . I want to assign conjugate prior distributions on both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, and then obtain the posterior distribution. How this can be done in R?

Answer (score 4):

I guess your answer can be found in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior. The conjugate prior is the Normal-inverse gamma with hyperparameters $\mu_0, \nu, \alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the R code to obtain the posterior distribution?

Comment: The posterior distribution has the form given  in the above Wiki link. You don't need to use R to find the posterior, although you can download the [Normal-Gamma Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NormalGamma/NormalGamma.pdf) if you need to have the normal-gamma PDF or CDF in R.